# select option selected заставить работать по onchange

Tags: javascript, html-select, onchange

Имею выпадающий список вида:

```html
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.value">     
    <option value="/catalog/12/?sort=name&amp;order=desc" selected="">name</option>         
    <option value="/catalog/12/?sort=catalog_PRICE_1">cena</option>
</select>
```

Не могу понять как заставить при нажатии на пункте с selected , также осуществлять переход по ссылке в value? Пробовал копать в сторону onclick, но тогда переход происходит сразу при попытке развернуть список.

Comment: Код работает как бы.. ;)

Comment: При нажатии на пункт  <option value="/catalog/12/?sort=name&amp;order=desc" selected="">name</option> нужно что-бы тоже происходил переход на адрес "/catalog/12/?sort=name&amp;order=desc"

Comment: как вы можете выбрать элемент, если он уже выбран по умолчанию) пустой опшен в начале как вариант

Comment: Задумка в том, что человек видит в браузере что option выбран, но имеет возможность выбрать его повторно (value имеет ссылку отличную от текущей страницы)